# NSLocalizedDescription=The certificate for this server is invalid Alamofire 5.2 Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofire-request

I am trying to create a login screen which uses Alamofire 5.2 to post the request but I seem to get the same error over and over again, I have tried to set up the info.plist file as many have suggested bu it was of no help. I tried to change the method in which I will post which was also of no help.

Please help Me our with this as I have been stuck with this for days with no results.

Request Function:

```
    func loginPlease(){
        
   
        
        let params = ["username":self.emailTextBox.text!, "password":self.PasswordTextBox.text!]
        
        let encodeURL = "domain url"
        
        let requestoAPI = AF.request(encodeURL, method: .post, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:["username":self.emailTextBox.text!, "password":self.PasswordTextBox.text!])
        
        
        requestoAPI.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
            
            print(response.request!)
            print(response.result)
            print(response.response)
            
        })
}
```

Alternative function (just to be sure)

```
    func loginPlease(){
        
   
        
        let params = ["username":self.emailTextBox.text!, "password":self.PasswordTextBox.text!]
        
        let encodeURL = "domain url"
        
        let requestoAPI = AF.request(encodeURL, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers:nil)
        
        
        requestoAPI.responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) -> Void in
            
            print(response.request!)
            print(response.result)
            print(response.response)
            
        })
}
```

Info.plist:
[image: info.plist]

Log:
[image]

Comment: You need to add a valid certificate to your website

Comment: I Purchased one and added it but it still seems to throw the same error. The Api works when using Postman.